# How to track variables that were computed after Matlab stops due to errors

Tags: matlab

I was running a very big program and I encountered an error that says

```
Error using ^. Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
```

at

```
A=(1-s)^theta / (1+www)^mm
```

My question is not about fixing this problem itself.

But the problem is I can't see which variable is causing this problem because when I type in s or theta or www or mm, Matlab doesn't know the value of them because the workspace doesn't contain these variables.

Matlab simply stops without saving these variables.

This is a very inconvenient feature because it takes very long time to simply replicate this issue.

I know I can view the variables if I just add

```
keyboard
```

just before where I see the error. But the mere fact that I have to rerun the whole code is irritating when it takes so much time to just reach this point.

How can I view the variables or at least the sizes of these variables when Matlab just stopped because of error?

Answer (score 1):

You could debug your program by setting a breakpoint inside your script or function – see the link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

This will enable you to see where the error is coming from.

Also, you might want to use “.^” instead of “^” if s and www are vectors – see the link:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html